# How to compile Scala source code into .Net

Tags: .net, scala, compiler-construction

I create a scala source file `test.scala`:

```
// the source code in test.scala
import System.Console
object TestMain extends Application {
    override def main(args: Array[String]) = {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello .NET World!")
    }
}
```

Not that I import the `System.Console` which is from the .Net library.

Before compiling, I download a `scala-msil` package from http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads/packages/scala-msil-2.8.1.final.sbp and then install it by `sbaz install -f scala-msil-2.8.1.final.sbp`.

After that, some scripts, such as `scalac-net.bat` used to compile *.scala to *.msil, is created in %SCALA_HOME%\bin and dlls, such as `microlib.dll`, `predef.dll` and `scalaruntime.dll`, in %SCALA_HOME%. Unfortunately I got the error when `scalac-net test.scala`

[image]

Can anyone give me a suggestion ??

PS: My scala version  is 2.8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binaries and sources for the latest (preview) version of Scala.NET (library and compiler) can be obtained via SVN:

```
svn co http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/svn-repos/scala/scala-experimental/trunk/bootstrap
```

Bootstrapping has been an important step, and ongoing work will add support for missing features (CLR generics, etc). That's work in progress.

A survivor's report on using Scala.NET on XNA at http://www.srtsolutions.com/tag/scala

Miguel Garcia http://lamp.epfl.ch/~magarcia/ScalaNET/

Comment: Thanks. It's work. But how about this ? Is it no longer be maintained ?